# Single table design of a chat app on DynamoDB, checking if on the right direction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-data-modeling

I am all new to NoSQL and specifically DynamoDB single table design. Have been going through a lot of videos and articles on the internet regarding the single-table design and finally I have put together a small design for a chat application which I am planning to build in the future.

The access patterns I have so far thought about are -

1. Get user details by User Id.
2. Get list of conversations the user is part of.
3. Get list of messages the user has created
4. Get all members of a conversation
5. Get all messages of a conversation

Also want to access messages of a conversation by a date range, so far I haven't figured out that one.

As per the below design, if I were to pull all messages of a conversation, is that going to pull the actual message in the message attribute which is in the message partition?

Here is the snip of the model I have created with some sample data on. Please let me know if I am in the right direction.

[image: Single Table Design - Table layout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As per the below design, if I were to pull all messages of a conversation, is that going to pull the actual message in the message attribute which is in the message partition?

No, it will only return the IDs of a message as the actual content is in a separate partition.

I'd propose a different model - it consists of a table with a Global Secondary Indexe (GSI1). The layout is like this:

Base Table:

- Partition Key: PK
- Sort Key: SK

Global Secondary Index GSI1:

- Partition Key: GSI1PK
- Sort Key: GSI1SK

#### Base Table

[image: Base Table]

#### GSI 1

[image: GSI1]

#### Access Patterns

> 1.) Get user details by User Id.

GetItem on Base Table with Partition Key = `PK = U#<id>` and Sort Key `SK = USER`

> 2.) Get list of conversations the user is part of.

Query on Base Table with Partition Key = `PK = U#<id>` and Sort Key `SK = starts_with(CONV#)`

> 3.) Get list of messages the user has created

Query on GSI1 with Partition Key `GSI1PK = U#<id>`

> 4.) Get all members of a conversation

Query on Base Table with Partition Key = `PK = CONV#<id>` and Sort Key `SK starts_with(U#)`

> 5.) Get all messages of a conversation

Query on Base Table with Partition Key `PK = CONV#<id>` and Sort Key `SK starts_with(MSG#)`

> 6.) Also want to access messages of a conversation by a date range, so far I haven't figured out that one.

DynamoDB does Byte-Order Sorting in a partition - if you format all dates according to ISO 8601 in the UTC timezone, you can make the range query, e.g.:

Query on Base Table with Partition Key `PK = CONV#<id>` and Sort Key `SK between(MSG#2021-09-20, MSG#2021-09-30)`

Comment: Thanks Maurice for the detailed explanation. Just want to know what would be more performant and economical. What if when a message is created, it's written both to the user partition and the conversation partition? This way also the 3rd access pattern works.

Comment: What's your use case for that access pattern? That's the one I understood least. From an economics perspective it shouldn't make much of a difference - you're duplicating the storage costs and read/write accesses in both cases. That's why I'd pick the solution with less overhead - i.e. GSI.

Comment: I have a feature planned to show the stats like the number of messages sent by user by week, month, etc, if the user is a member of a group chat. That would be the main user case.

Comment: In that case it's probably better to store an item with the aggregate stats, connect a Lambda to the DynamoDB Stream and have that Lambda update the stats when new messages are created/deleted. That's cheaper.

Comment: Okay sounds good. Thanks Maurice.